# Filter deep populeted field in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose

How to filter products by deep nested populated fields. catalogProduct is an ObjectId (ref to catalog product). category is an ObjectId inside catalogProduct (ref to categories). Categories is an array of category ids.

```js
products = await StorageModel
                .find({"catalogProduct.category": {$in: categories }})
                .skip((page-1)*8)
                .limit(8)
                .populate({path: "catalogProduct", populate: {path: "category", select: "name"}})
                .select('-__v')
                .sort({_id: -1});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to do a `$lookup` on the catelogProduct collection so that you can access the catelogProduct data in the query.

Unfortunately that's only available when using Mongo Aggregation, however aggregation is very powerful and is perfect for this sort of thing. You could do something like this:

```
const products = await StorageModel.aggregate([
    { $lookup: {  // Replace the Catelog Product ID with the Catelog Product
        from: "catelogProduct",
        localField: "catelogProduct",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "catelogProduct"
    } },
    { $lookup: {  // Replace the Category ID with the Category
        from: "categories",
        localField: "catelogProduct.category",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "catelogProduct.category"
    } },
    { $addFields: {  // Replace the Category with its name
        "catelogProduct.category": "$catelogProduct.category.name"   
    } },
    { $match: {
        "catalogProduct.category": { $in: categories }
    } },
    { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
    { $skip: (page - 1) * 8 },
    { $limit: 8 }
]);
```

Ideally you wouldn't do the `$lookup` until you've paginated the results (using `$skip` and `$limit`), but in this case it makes sense to do the `$lookup` first. Make sure you've got an index on `catelogProduct._id` and `categories._id` to optimize the query.

For more info on `$lookup`, look at [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) article. For more info on Mongo Aggregation, look at [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) article.